# Disable Responsive Design on Capital Theme - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I am creating a website and I am trying to disable the responsive design feature.  When I resize my browser, a few things get jumbled up, and I am not experienced with responsive design coding.  Here is the link to my website

http://www.jiddrs.com

Comment: You should be interested in responsive design. http://electricpulp.com/notes/you-like-apples/

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this, especially without knowing the code. It looks like the CSS for the search bar is out of place. Wordpress is a CMS that uses PHP to deliver content from the server. It compiles on a long running list of conditional statements that serve up content as needed.

Responsive CSS is completed by media queries. There's likely one stylesheet inside of your theme's folder labeled responsive.css or something similar.

Media queries look like this

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
.classChange { style }
}
```